# how to convert fix length file to csv file in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, fixed-length-record, fixed-length-file

In the file each columns have fix size.

Is there any library or function available using that we can convert easily to CSV file ?

There are four columns in the file.

```
1st - 1233212Q1AQYHDVCS1221
2nd - 64342343EDV53234212
3rd - 11123321111124122
4th - 52122211
```

**Sample records** :

```
1233212Q1AQYHDVCS1221 64342343EDV53234212 11123321111124122
52122211

1233212Q1AQYHDVCS1221 64342343EDV53234212 11123321111124122
52122211

1233212Q1AQYHDVCS1221 64342343EDV53234212 11123321111124122
52122211

1233212Q1AQYHDVCS1221 64342343EDV53234212 11123321111124122
52122211

1233212Q1AQYHDVCS1221 64342343EDV53234212 11123321111124122
52122211
```

I would like to convert straight forward that file to CSV.

Comment: what is 52122211 after each line?

Comment: 52122211 is column .. !!

Comment: your line 1 has 3 column and line 2 has 1 column and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the columns are separated by whitespace, simple sed can do it:

`sed 's/[\t ]+/,/g' input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: the question has the python tag.

Comment: 11123321111124122 value converted to 1.11233211111241E+016.
I have tried `sed 's/[\t ]+/,/g' input.txt > output.csv`

Comment: Both values are same, I think it might be related to how your csv editor displays the data. Try opening it with a text editor like `vim`, `nano` or `notepad` to verify